# No logger output in sheets

Tags: google-sheets, google-apps-script

I am getting no output from the logger in sheets.  I am a noob, although a 30+ year programmer. Here is my function:

```
function onChange(e) { 
  var spreadsheet = e.source;
  var cell = spreadsheet.getCurrentCell();
  var row = cell.getRow();
  var col = cell.getColumn();
  Logger.log('onEdit: row %s  column  %s',row,col);
  if (row >= 35 && row <= 45) {
    if (col == 1) CheckedExpense();
  }
};

function sendlog() {
  var recipient = Session.getActiveUser().getEmail();
  var subject = 'Execution Log ';
  var body = Logger.getLog();
  MailApp.sendEmail(recipient, subject, body);
};
```

Since I was getting no output from the view -> logs screen I added the email function, also no output.  Ah, and the function is executing and completing successfully.

Comment: It's not clear how you are calling `onChange` and `sendLog`. Are you using installable triggers?

Comment: onChange is a trigger, and sendLog is tied to ctrl-alt-shift-7.

Comment: I can't even find the "view -> logs" menu.  is that supposed to be on the spreadsheet itself? I only see: Show, Freeze, Comments, Zoom and others like that

Comment: @ekkis  You should look at Google Apps Script editor. Please read https://developers.google.com/apps-scripts/guides/sheets

Answer (score 0):

The Logger logs aren't permanent. They are cleared on each execution.

One alternative is to use `console.log` instead of `Logger.log`. For details please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging

---

## Update

Since this question was posted, several changes have been made to Google Apps Script. Many online resources about Google Apps Script have become obsolete, so I encourage people to first look at the [official site](https://developers.google.com/apps-script), as most of its content is updated when a change is made.

Still, some people might take time to catch how logging works with Google Apps Script. The first thing to understand is that Google Apps Script is a digital service encompassing several components. The basic use of a `Logger` or `console` will not write logs to the web browser's JavaScript console. As I mentioned above, for details, please read https://developers.google.com/apps-script/guides/logging

1. All the Apps Script projects, aka "scripts", created with an account and shared with it can be found at https://scripts.google.com.
2. The persistent logs can be accessed by clicking the three-dot button at the right of *script* name.

File name
[image: A script shown at https://script.google.com]

The bottom part of the three-dot menu

[image: The bottom part of the three-dot menu]

Logs in the Apps Script service are kept only for a few days. There are several alternatives to keep them longer and permanently, like writing the log messages to a spreadsheet or text file.